# Transmitting audio through socket (UDP) but not playing back properly

Tags: c, unix, alsa

I'm trying to transmit from the client side a wav file through socket (UDP) and have the server playing the wav file by means of the ALSA library.

Since my coding level in C is very low I've first learnt how to set up a communication between client and server via sockets and interchange text messages.

Afterwards I've learnt how to play a wav file with ALSA by redirecting the stdin when running the playback app.

I've tried to joint both code (UDPServer.c + playback.c) files and when I pass the stdin to the UDPClient.c file it sends it to the UDPServer.c but it's just a pure tone instead of the actual music file that I'm trying to pass.

I don't know how exactly to pass the file into the UDPClient.c in order for it to send it to the socket to the server.

UDPServer.c

```
// Server side implementation of UDP client-server model 

// Libraries
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

// CONSTANTS
#define PORT     8080 
#define MAXLINE  2048
/* Use the newer ALSA API */
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

// FUNCTION DECLARATION
int audio_play (char signal);

// Main code 
int main() { 
int sockfd; 
char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
char *hello = "AUDIO PLAYBACK FINISH"; 
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 

// Creating socket file descriptor 
if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
    perror("socket creation failed"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 

memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr)); 

// Filling server information 
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4 
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

// Bind the socket with the server address 
if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) { 
    perror("bind failed"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 

int len, n; 

len = sizeof(cliaddr); //len is value/result 

// Receive a mesage from the socket
n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len); 
buffer[n] = '\0'; 
//printf("Client : %s\n", buffer); 
audio_play(buffer);


// Send a message on the socket
sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello), MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, len); 
printf("PLAYING AUDIO???.\n"); 

return 0; 
} 


// FUNCTIONS

int audio_play (char s)
{
   long                 loops;
   int                  rc;
   int                  size;
   snd_pcm_t            *handle;
   snd_pcm_hw_params_t  *params;
   unsigned int         val;
   int                  dir;
   snd_pcm_uframes_t    frames;
   char                 *buffer;

   /* Open PCM device for playback. */
   rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);

   if (rc < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open pcm device: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
        exit(1);
   }

   /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
   snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
   /* Fill it in with default values. */
   snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);
   /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */
   /* Interleaved mode */
   snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
   /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
   snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
   /* Two channels (stereo) */
   snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);
   /* 48000 bits/second sampling rate */
   val = 48000;
   snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &val, &dir);
   /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
   frames = 32;
   snd_ pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);

   /* Write the parameters to the driver */
   rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);

   if (rc < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
   exit(1);
   }

   /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
   snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, &dir);
   size = frames * 4; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
   buffer = (char *) malloc(size);
   /* We want to loop for 5 seconds */
   snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &val, &dir);
   /* 5 seconds in microseconds divided by
    * period time */
   loops = 5000000 / val;

   while (loops > 0) {
       loops--;
       //    rc = read(0, buffer, size);
       rc = s;

       if (rc == 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "end of file on input\n");
           break;

       } else if (rc != size) {
          fprintf(stderr, "short read: read %d bytes\n", rc);
       }
       rc = snd_pcm_writei(handle, buffer, frames);

       if (rc == -EPIPE) {
       /* EPIPE means underrun */
           fprintf(stderr, "underrun occurred\n");
           snd_pcm_prepare(handle);

       } else if (rc < 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "error from writei: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));

       }  else if (rc != (int)frames) {
           fprintf(stderr, "short write, write %d frames\n", rc);
       }
   }

   snd_pcm_drain(handle);
   snd_pcm_close(handle);
   free(buffer);

}
```

UDPClient.c

```
// Client side implementation of UDP client-server model 
// Libraries
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 

// CONSTANTS
#define PORT     8080 
#define MAXLINE  2048

// Main code
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    int sockfd; 
    char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *data = "Here is where the file of audio should be?";
    struct sockaddr_in   servaddr; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    int n, len; 

    // Send a message on the socket 
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)data, strlen(data), MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    printf("AUDIO SENT.\n"); 

    // Receive a message from the socket
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, &len); 
    buffer[n] = '\0'; 
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer); 

    close(sockfd); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You need to read about file handling in C, specifically `fopen`, `fread`, and `fclose`. You also need to be aware that UDP packets must be less than 64K bytes. Unless the file is smaller than that, you need to read from the file and write to the socket in small chunks. Which then raises the issues that UDP can drop packets, and may deliver packets out of order. So you might want to use TCP instead.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.